# MQTT Java - How to end connection after receiving a certain number of messages?

Tags: java, mqtt

I'm having a problem writing correct code with MQTT in Java. My goal is to subscribe to a topic and watch if some kind of messages are coming. Then, if it hits certain amount, the function will return true.

The problem is the function returns the value sooner than the subscribe counts its goal.

Here's my fragment of code:

```
@Override
public Boolean call() throws Exception {
    mqttClient.subscribe(couple.getTopic().getUrl(), (topic, message) -> {
        System.out.println(new String(message.getPayload()) + "=" + couple.getMessage().getJson());
        if (new String(message.getPayload()).equals(couple.getMessage().getJson())) {
            System.out.println("Match");
            this.accurance++;
            System.out.println("accurance :" + this.accurance);
            if (this.accurance >= this.goal) {
                //sendMessage(couple);
                mqttClient.unsubscribe(couple.getTopic().getUrl());
                return;
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Not match");
        }
    });
    return true;
}
```

Comment: The `subscribe` method is asynchronous. This method will almost immediately return `true` in all cases.

Comment: I know that but how do i let other functions let know that the condition was completed.

Comment: Depending on your use case, you could set a local variable (like `this.completed = true`) and check that field in your other methods, or call another method at the same place you unsubscribe (like `complete()`).